# Find common first columns and print the second one if they are matched

Tags: awk

File1

```
3.5 22
5. 23
4.2 42
4.5 44
```

File2

```
3.5  
3.7
5.
6.5
```

Desired output:

```
 3.5 22
 5. 23
```

I prefer to use 'awk'.

Comment: You should really show what you've tried and explain where you've got stuck.

Comment: Sorry guys it's the least effort I made while asking a question indeed. I am very familiar of this site though. I deserved the comments. Never happen once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `oneliner` should do the *trick*:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' file2 file1
```

**Explanation**

`NR==FNR{a[$1];next}`: stores the `keys` presents in `file2`.

`$1 in a`: will print the line if the current `key` from `file1` is in `a` where we stored the `keys`of `file2`.

From the [docs](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_12.html#SEC114):

> If you **refer to an array element that has no recorded value**, the value
>   of the reference is "", the null ... **Such a reference automatically
>   creates that array element, with the null string as its value**.

**Note**

As @JonathanLeffler explain in comments `$1 in a` is used instead `a[$1]` to avoid creating elements in `a` when there's no match.

**Note 2**

As @EdMorton points `a[$1]++` wastes processor cycles. We can use just `a[$1]` to initialize  the *associative* array.

**Original code**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]' file2 file1
```

**Thanks** *Jonathan* && *Ed*.

Comment: Would you be better off with `$1 in a` (instead of `a[$1]`) to avoid creating elements in `a` when there's no match?  For small scale files there's no material difference.  If, OTOH, there are several million values in `file2` of which only a few are represented in `file1`, then it might matter.  (There again, with gigabytes of main memory, it may not matter much even with millions of values.)